# Using `getopt` to take in multiple options after one hyphen

Tags: c++, unix, ls, getopt

So I am writing a small program that is supposed to implement a basic version of `ls` and takes in the optional flags `a`, `l`, and `R`. I have basically everything else covered, but, for the past week or so, I have not been able to figure out how to pass in multiple flags after one hyphen. For example, my program should be able to take in `ls -alR`. However, the code that I have for this (shown below and modified from getopt's man page) does not work in cases like these. Cases like `ls -a -l -R` work just fine.

Is `getopt` not able to handle these kind of options? Should I look into `getopt_long` or `getopt_long_only`, or even look at different libraries (for example boost options)?

```
//gloabl indicator variables
bool aflag, lflag, Rflag; 

//sets Truth values to boolean global indicator variables 
//will tell if a, l, or R flags passed into argv
//FIXME need to fix case(s) -alR,...
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{       
        int index;
        int c;
        opterr = 0;

        while( (c = getopt (argc, argv, "alR")) != -1 )
        {
                switch (c)
                {
                        case 'a':
                                aflag = true;
                                break;
                        case 'l':
                                lflag = true;
                                break;
                        case 'R':
                                Rflag = true;
                                break;
                        case '?':
                                if (isprint (optopt))
                                  fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt); 
                        default:
                                abort ();
                }
        }

        // prints out truth values for flags
        printf ("aflag = %d, lflag = %d, Rflag = %d\n", aflag, lflag, Rflag);

        //prints out non option arguments   
        for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
        printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);

        //DO OTHER STUFF
        return 0; 
}
```

I should add that these flags require no arguments. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I compiled your snippet on Ubuntu 14.04 and it behaves as expected. `
./t; ./t -a; ./t -al; ./t -alR
aflag = 0, lflag = 0, Rflag = 0
aflag = 1, lflag = 0, Rflag = 0
aflag = 1, lflag = 1, Rflag = 0
aflag = 1, lflag = 1, Rflag = 1
`

Comment: Perhaps you are using some non-standard version of getopt?

Comment: @lothar Well, how about that! It doesn't work in my ls program, but like you, I compiled and ran the above snippet in a separate file and it works just fine. Now to figure out what's wrong with my main program! :D 
Thanks!

Comment: @n.m. I am using the GNU C Library's getopt. I tried this snippet on Ubuntu 14.04 as well and it seems to work fine. Must have something to do with my school's cs dept. ssh server that I am using.